# NumPy: construct squares along diagonal of matrix / expand diagonal matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

Suppose you have either two arrays:

```py
index = [1, 2, 3]
counts = [2, 3, 2]
```

or a singular array

```py
arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

How can I efficiently construct the matrix

```py
[
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3]
]
```

with NumPy?

I know that

```py
square = np.zeros((7, 7))
np.fill_diagnol(square, arr) # see arr above
```

produces

```py
[
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]
]
```

How do I "expand" the diagonal by `n` where `n` is `counts[index-1]` for the values specified by `index[I]`

```
tmp = np.array((arr * N)).reshape((len(arr), len(arr)) 
np.floor( (tmp + tmp.T) / 2 ) # <-- this is closer


array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [1., 1., 2., 2., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2., 2., 3., 3.]])
```

This gets what I want, but probably doesn't scale that well?

```
riffled = list(zip(index, counts))
riffled
# [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2)]
```

```
a = np.zeros((len(arr), len(arr))) # 7, 7 square
last = 0 # <-- keep track of current sub square
for i, c in riffled:
    a[last:last+c, last:last+c] = np.ones((c, c)) * i 
    last += c # <-- shift square
```

yield

```
array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 3., 3.]])
```

Comment: `np.equal.outer(arr, arr) * arr`

Comment: @user3483203 also works! thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try broadcasting:

```
idx = np.repeat(np.arange(len(counts)), counts)
np.where(idx==idx[:,None], arr, 0)
# or
# arr * (idx==idx[:,None])
```

Output;

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3]])
```

Comment: That works! Note to readers `arr` in question is a Python list so for this to work, convert it to numpy via `np.array(arr)`

Comment: @SumNeuron. You can just do `np.reshape(arr, (-1, 1)) == arr` to avoid an explicit conversion. It's cheaper to do an explicit conversion though.

Comment: Note that this only works if the blocks in `arr` are different (e.g., `arr = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])` wouldn't work)

Comment: @mozway just out of curiosity do you have an adjustment for that use case?

Comment: @SumNeuron not for now, I had a solution similar to that of Quang when I realized this downside ;)

Comment: @mozway see updated answer. We simply don't use `npindex` as a reference.

Comment: @QuangHoang I just posted something similar ;) (sorry for the lag, not in front of computer)

Answer (score 10):

You can use scipy.linalg.block_diag to make that work:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as linalg


a = 1*np.ones((2,2))
b = 2*np.ones((3,3))
c = 3*np.ones((2,2))

superBlock = linalg.block_diag(a,b,c)

print(superBlock)

#returns
#[[1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 2. 2. 2. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 3. 3.]]
```

if you want to get there from a list of values and a list of counts you can do this:

```
values = [1,2,3]
counts = [2,3,2]

mats = []
for v,c in zip(values,counts):
    thisMatrix = v*np.ones((c,c))
    mats.append( thisMatrix )


superBlock = linalg.block_diag(*mats)


print(superBlock)
```

Comment: So `mats = [np.full((c, c), v) for v, c in zip(values, counts)]`?

Comment: This is a good approach.

Comment: This is perfect if the user only needs to work with dense matrices after this creation step.  However if all of the data can be sparsely described like the example, there could also be some benefit in using the sparse versions: scipy.sparse.block_diag   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.block_diag.html#scipy.sparse.block_diag

Comment: @MikeHolcomb want to propose an edit? that could be great to have a better anwer (or make your own i'll upvote it)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a generic solution.

##### starting from the index/count:

```py
index = [1, 2, 1]
counts = [2, 3, 2]

arr = np.repeat(index, counts)
arr2 = np.repeat(range(len(index)), counts)
np.where(arr2 == arr2[:, None], arr, 0)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]])
```

##### starting from the array version:

```py
arr = np.array([1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2])

arr2 = np.cumsum(np.diff(arr,prepend=np.nan) != 0)
np.where(arr2 == arr2[:, None], arr, 0)
```

output:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]])
```